# How to simulate CDF and PDF of Random varible

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, matlab, random

In may wireless communication they dirive a CDF and PDF then they conferme the theorical result with simulation 
My question how the sumulat.
For example suppose we have 3 random varibles $h_i$ wish are zero-mean,
independent, circularly symmetric complex Gaussian random variables with variances $\delta^2_i$. $|h_i|^2$ is expontial with parametre $\beta_i$. We want to drive PDF and CDF of random varible $$z=\max\{|h_1|^2,|h_2|^2,|h_3|^2\}$$.

the CDF of $z$ is
$$F_Z(z)=(1-e^{(-\beta z)})^3$$ 
and pdf 
$$ P_Z(z)=3\beta e^{(-\beta z)}(1-e^{(-\beta z)})^2 $$.
 My question how to plot the theorical CDF and PDF in matlab and do simulation. 
In matlab we generate $h$ as follow
$$h=(randn(1,Nsym)+1j*randn(1,Nsym))$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you want to generate samples of the max of three so do

```
h = max(abs(randn(3,N)+ j * randn(3,N)).^2);
```

Now $h$ is the $1\times N$ vector you want the sample statistics of. For the empirical CDF, you can do

```
CDFx = sort(h);
CDFy = (1 : length(h)) / length(h);
```

There's also a builtin ecdf function in newer versions.

For the empirical PDF, there's a few options... there's Kernel densities which have a matlab builtin you can search for. The most straightforward 'by hand' is just doing a normalized histogram

```
[pdfy, pdfx] = hist(h,nbins);
pdfy = pdfy/trapz(pdfx,pdfy); % normalize
```

**edit**

More detail:

```
N = 10000;
nbins = 50;

h = max(abs(randn(3,N)+ j * randn(3,N)).^2);

CDFx = sort(h);
eCDFy = (1 : length(h)) / length(h);
tCDFy = (1-exp(-.5*CDFx)).^3;

figure(1);
plot(CDFx,eCDFy,CDFx,tCDFy);
legend('CDF from random numbers', 'exact CDF')

[ePDFy, PDFx] = hist(h,nbins);
ePDFy = ePDFy/trapz(PDFx,ePDFy);
tPDFy = 3 * .5 * exp(-.5 * PDFx).*(1-exp(-.5 * PDFx)).^2;

figure(2);
plot(PDFx,ePDFy,PDFx,tPDFy);
legend('PDF from random numbers', 'exact PDF')
```

Comment: hi spaceisdarkgreen  i will try your code. thank you but what about theorical

Comment: @Mokhtar That's just a matter of plotting the functional forms you derived (which, for what it's worth, look correct to me). And I guess if you don't want to worry about making a grid for the x values, just using pdfx or cdfx will be fine if they are dense enough.

Comment: Hi spaceisdarkgreen  again i will add figure to understand me

Comment: i Have add the figuer the analisis of cdf and pdf is very complicated however i want to now how the use simulation and get exact the theorical graph. Thank you.

Comment: @Mokhtar What do you mean by 'do the simulation'. Do you mean by drawing the random numbers as in $h=...$ above? It's not at all clear from the plots you posted what is being plotted. I added code that will test plot the empirical distributions out of the random number generator and also plot the exact functional forms you derived.

Comment: hi  i will add the CDF expression as figure because its long. Lets do better now i am reading this paper when i finished iwill send you the algorrithm because here we are in wireless communication system and we have random varible and z random varible as follow $z=\frac{XY}{X+Y+1}$ where are alsso X and Y diffrent random varible so the authos first direve CDF and DPF then vaidate with similation. ok thank you so much

Comment: I fixed your formatting. It's tedious to insert these spaces by hand, but there is a UI button that looks like {} to do it for you.

Comment: @Ian Thank you.

Comment: ok thanks but i have lasst quetion why use $$CDFx = sort(h);$$
in 
$$tCDFy = (1-exp(-.5*CDFx)).^3;$$ can we for exmple $x=0:0.1:14$?

Comment: @Mokhtar For plotting the functional forms, you could really make your x values any set of values you want that go along most of the relevant parts of the function and are dense enough to look like a nice smooth curve. CDFx happens to fit the bill, (it's not evenly spaced, but that doesn't really matter), so I just reused it. Something like tCDFx = 0:0.1:14; tCDFy = (1-exp(-.5*tCDFx)).^3 looks like it would work just fine.

Comment: ok awesome it was very help full thank you a gain. Good Lock.